# Circle not visible as I drag the mouse in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm creating a small paint program in JavaFX and have got a circle creation tool. At the moment, I can draw the circle properly, but unlike my other tools I can't see the circle as it's being created (i.e. as I'm dragging my mouse). It is only when I release the mouse that I see the circle (drawn with the correct dimensions). I tried adding in a `strokeOval()` method as I dragged, but it creates a strange "teardrop" like circle. I have tried everything - can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
public CircleController(Canvas canvas, Scene mainScene, BorderPane borderPane) {

    this.borderPane = borderPane;
    this.mainScene = mainScene;
    this.graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    circle = new Circle();
    circle.setStrokeWidth(1.0);
    circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    mousePressed = event -> {
        startingPosX = event.getX();
        startingPosY = event.getY();
        borderPane.getChildren().add(circle);

    };

    mouseReleased = event -> {
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(circle);
        double width = Math.abs(event.getX() - startingPosX);
        double height = Math.abs(event.getY() - startingPosY);
        graphicsContext.strokeOval(startingPosX, startingPosY, width, height);
        graphicsContext.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        removeListeners();
    };

    mouseDragged = event -> {
        circle.setCenterX(event.getX() - startingPosX);
        circle.setCenterY(event.getY() - startingPosY);

    };
}
```

This above code creates the circle correctly, but cannot be seen until I release the mouse. I apply the above EventHandlers to my scene:

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    mainScene.setOnMousePressed(mousePressed);
    mainScene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDragged);
    mainScene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseReleased);
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Teardrop-like effect??? What exactly do you mean by that? What is the code you used to draw? And what's that circle supposed to represent? And why do you use a `BorderPane` for this???

Comment: @fabian, The code I use to draw is above. The circle is just a circle for my paint program. In regards to why I use a BorderPane, it's out of choice - is there something preventing me from seeing the circle because I use a borderPane?

Comment: And why are you registering what the mouse listeners in what appears to be an event handler? What event is it handling?

Comment: @James_D this is an example of one of my events: `private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressed;`

Comment: @xn139 Actually, that's not an example of an event, it's an example of an event handler. But I can see the code already. My question was: why are you registering the handlers in another event handler? What is the event handler in your second code block attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're drawing a **oval** not a **circle**. The `Circle` class cannot appropriately handle this. You need `Ellipse`. Furthermore note that dragging up/left from the start of the gesture results in weird behavior of the oval, since it's always drawn in the first quadrant of the coordinate system with origin at the start of the drag gesture.

The following code should allow drawing the oval in every quadrant and also use a `Ellipse` as "preview":

```
// TODO: replace circle field with ellipse field of type Ellipse
ellipse = new Ellipse();
ellipse.setStrokeWidth(1.0);
ellipse.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ellipse.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

mousePressed = event -> {
    startingPosX = event.getX();
    startingPosY = event.getY();
    ellipse.setCenterX(startingPosX);
    ellipse.setCenterY(startingPosY);
    ellipse.setRadiusX(0);
    ellipse.setRadiusY(0);
    borderPane.getChildren().add(ellipse);
};

mouseReleased = event -> {
    borderPane.getChildren().remove(ellipse);
    double width = Math.abs(event.getX() - startingPosX);
    double height = Math.abs(event.getY() - startingPosY);
    graphicsContext.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    graphicsContext.strokeOval(Math.min(startingPosX, event.getX()), Math.min(startingPosY, event.getY()), width, height);
    removeListeners();
};

mouseDragged = event -> {
    ellipse.setCenterX((event.getX() + startingPosX) / 2);
    ellipse.setCenterY((event.getY() + startingPosY) / 2);
    ellipse.setRadiusX(Math.abs((event.getX() - startingPosX) / 2));
    ellipse.setRadiusY(Math.abs((event.getY() - startingPosY) / 2));
};
```